# Discord bot not connecting

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ctx

Anybody know why my bot is not connecting to my discord voice channel?

```py
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


@client.command()
async def join(ctx):

        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect
```

Comment: It's `await channel.connect()` not `await channel.connect`

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):

    vc = ctx.author.voice
    if vc:
        await vc.channel.connect()
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the `channel.connect` method, plus `channel.connect` is a coroutine, and needs to be awaited, `await channel.connect()`